# C# Tasks - Why a noop line is needed in this case

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I am reading the source code of Interactive Extensions and have found a [line](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/master/Ix.NET/Source/System.Interactive.Async/TaskExt.cs#L69) that I cannot understand:

```
public static Task<bool> UsingEnumerator(this Task<bool> task, IDisposable disposable)
{
    task.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        if (t.IsFaulted)
        {
            var ignored = t.Exception; // don't remove!
        }

        if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled || !t.Result)
            disposable.Dispose();
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);

    return task;
}
```

I also do not see any relevant remarks in the docs for `IsFaulted` or `Exception` properties.

Why this line `var ignored = t.Exception; // don't remove!` is needed in this context?

A related question: I thought that such lines are optimized away in the Release mode, but given the comment and intent here that is not the case (if the code is correct). So why does this line stay in the Release mode?

Comment: In .net 4 the task finaliser throws an exception if a task is faulted but its `Exception` property is not accessed.

Comment: @Lee thanks! That is actually written in the docs for `Exception` property but I didn't understood it on the first read.

Comment: with respect to it being removed in release builds, the `ignored` local will be removed, but `t.Exception` will be resolved to its value (because it might, and in this case does, cause side effects) it's just that the return value is dropped on the floor in release builds instead of stored in an unread variable.

Comment: Is this true for all properties or only for ones with side effects? If that was a field of some object and not a property, would the whole line and the if block be optimized away?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That line is the difference between **an observed exception and an unobserved one.**

In .Net 4.0 a task with an unobserved exception will throw an `UnobservedTaskException` and tear down the entire application:

> "If you do not wait on a task that propagates an exception, or access its Exception property, the exception is escalated according to the .NET exception policy when the task is garbage-collected."

From [Exception Handling (Task Parallel Library)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

That was changed in .Net 4.5 with `async-await`, although you can get the old behavior back using the app.config (`<ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions enabled="true"/>`).

There's also an event (`TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException`) that allows you to handle such faulted tasks before the application crashes. That event is still being raised in .Net 4.5 and above.

Comment: @Servy I disagree. It changed because `async-await` was excepted to make abandoning tasks common which wasn't before.